# Performance comparison of Creating a List of Objects vs Creating a Dictionary using Linq?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework-4

We are using Entity framework in our project. To Explain my question, I will take example of Students and Professors.

> Assumption: There can be multiple students under one professor but each
>   student has only professor assigned.

1. First I will find distinct Ids from List of `Student`'s.

   ```
   List<int> profIds= students.Select(s => s.profId).Distinct();
   ```
2. Then I try to update the name of professor under which he is doing project, I already have `profesors` object of type `IEntityRepository<Professor>` . I have two alternative approaches for this step.

**First:**

```
Dictionary<int, string> profDictionary = professors.SearchFor(x => 
        profIds.Contains(x.Id))
       .ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => 
          string.Format("{0} {1} {p.FirstName,p.LastName));

foreach(var stu in students)
        stu.ProfName = profDictionary[stu.profId];
```

**Second:**

```
profList = professors.SearchFor(profIds.Contains(x.Id))
                .Select(item => new ProfessorDTO()
                {
                    Id= item.Id,
                    FirstName = item.FirstName,
                    LastName = item.LastName
                }).ToList();

foreach(var stu in students)
        stu.ProfName = profList.Where(x => x.id == stu.profId).Select(x => 
             string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to know, Which approach is best in this case: Creating a dictionary of a List? 
And Why?

Comment: Where do you want to use your result?

Comment: This is *your* application, surely it's up to you to decide which approach is best? If you want to know which approach is quicker, you have the data, benchmark them...

Comment: @Christos I want to use the results for Reports. Above code is part of Service/DAL method which RDL report will call directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like a `GroupBy` clause would be better suited here

```
var studentsByProfessor = students.GroupBy(x => x.profId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ProfName = professors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == g.Key)
            .Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)),
        Students = g.ToList()
    });
```